# Linux process data structure

Tags: linux, data-structures, process, operating-system

According to GNU website the linux shell uses the following data structure for a process :

```
typedef struct process
{
  struct process *next;       /* next process in pipeline */
  char **argv;                /* for exec */
  pid_t pid;                  /* process ID */
  char completed;             /* true if process has completed */
  char stopped;               /* true if process has stopped */
  int status;                 /* reported status value */
} process;
```

Why can't the shell use the [task_struct](http://140.120.7.21/LinuxRef/ProcMana/ProcessManaging.html)  data structure for a process when it is already present in the kernel. Why use a separate data structure ?

Comment: The shell does not have access to the kernel.

Comment: @user3344003 Thanks. So an we say that the above data structure is an abstraction so that people can't change process level variables required for scheduling etc. ?